# pyinstaller exe file does not open

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I made exe file from with pyinstaller. Exe file is 38 MB, it has `tkinter` but when I click exe file cmd window opens up, CPU works 100%, I waited 10 minutes nothing happened.

How can I resolve it?
COde is below;

```
import sys, subprocess, pkg_resources

required={'tk'}
installed={pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing=required - installed

if missing:
    python=sys.executable
    subprocess.check_call([python,'-m','pip','install', *missing],stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)

import openpyxl
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Your App crawler")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)

mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=('N'))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

feet = tk.StringVar()
feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=21, textvariable=feet)
feet_entry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(tk.N) ,ipadx=100)
feet_entry.focus()

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="enter SC url ").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=('N'))

def crawler():

    ttk.Label(mainframe, text="...data retrieving finished. Check file ...").grid(column=0, row=6, sticky='W')
    root.update()

button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="scrape", command=crawler)
button.grid(column=3, row=7, sticky=tk.S)
root.bind("<Return>", crawler)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this part of the code is causing the issue, removing it will fix the issue.

```py
import sys, subprocess, pkg_resources

required={'tk'}
installed={pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing=required - installed

if missing:
    python=sys.executable
    subprocess.check_call([python,'-m','pip','install', *missing],stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

basically pkg_resources looks for `tk`, but it doesn't find it ... because it's inside the executable, it cannot be "found" on your disk, so it opens a new process that tries to install it, this calls `python` with some arguments but your `python` variable now points to your executable, it will start a new instance of your app ... which will start another version of your app etc.

pyinstaller should package `tk` if it is imported inside your module, so you don't have to "install" it manually.